# Starting Windows services from a Python script

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I am trying to start Windows services using a python script.
I have been able to start & stop services like Telnet using

```
subprocess.call("net start Telnet")

os.system("net start Telnet")
```

But for services like '**Task Scheduler**'(with multiple words), I get a

> syntax/service name invalid error

have tried [],'',but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use changing quotes trick. Use single quotes outside and double quotes inside.

```
subprocess.call('net start "task scheduler"')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this but It didn't work too....
But I have been able to get it done using the module **pywin32**.

**win32serviceutil in pywin32** is specifically for working with Windows services. 
Thanks!!